# How to connect to WSS with authorize ID in Advanced Rest Client

Tags: authentication, testing, websocket, advanced-rest-client

I'm absolutely new in WS but have experience with HTTP. 
I need to test the WebSocket application and I want to connect to WSS with Advanced Rest Client and manually send some requests (as I do it in Postman to test Rest API).

The authentication is realized with using ID what looks like 
xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx and it keeps in the local storage of my browser.

and my WSS server URL looks like wss://test.test.eu

When I trying to connect to wss://test.test.eu I received an Unknown Error. I understand what it is because of I need to provide the authentication ID to the server. So, I have this ID in xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx format.
I tried to connect to wss://test.test.eu/xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx  but it doesnt work.

Can anybody help me - how can I use my ID what keeps in the local storage?

Comment: I have the same problem. It looks like that websocket in ARC do not work at all. When trying to connect to websocket I have no logs in the server of even attempt of login. Also ARC behaves strangely displaying empty window. I do not know if the project is supported. So many questions on stackoverflow with no answers.